# How do I specify a spatial reference when using da.InsertCursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

When using an InsertCursor, I can specify a spatial reference per
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000002z000000.

I'm using da.InsertCursor because that's what everyone tells me to use and I've encountered no problems with it. How do I specify a spatial reference when using a da.InsertCursor?

Spatial reference is not even mentioned on the help page...
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w0000000t000000

Comment: You may be able to change it with the [environment setting](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000005000000) but I'm not 100% sure the cursor honors it since usually the objects already have a SR. Also although the da version of the search cursor is usually recommended especially for large datasets, but you can still use the old cursor.

Comment: I'm wondering why you want to specify a spatial reference. You would probably be better off testing and reprojecting the geometry of the incoming rows before you do the insert.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is assumed if you are passing in your own geometry, the geometry objects will have a spatial reference:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\some_gdb.gdb\some_fc'
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, 'SHAPE@') as rows:
    for pnt in [(-93.2, 41.1), (-92.8, 44.7)]:
        rows.insertRow([arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(*pnt), sr)])
```

Comment: Hey DenaliHardtail. Yeah, the spatial reference is specified in the feature class or geometry object, not in the da.cursor row. The FC should already have a spatial reference - try arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name or you can use the Define Projection tool to specify a spatial reference at the FC level. Otherwise you can pass the spatial reference to the geometry object like crmackey has described.